# How do I test a a Field component from React Redux with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, field, react-testing-library, react-forms

This is my Field:

```
<Field
 name="postcode"
 label="Postcode"
 nonReduxFormInputProps={{ id: 'postcode' }}
 component={TextInput}
 />
```

In my test, I've done this so far and it passes but I think it's wrong because for the name, 'postcode' in the code starts with a lowercase, but in my test it only passes if the name is with a capital 'P'. I also don't know how I would test the label, nonReduxFormInputProps and component.

```
describe('postcode field', () => {
  it('should render a Field component with correct props', () => {
    render(<TestForm />);
    expect(screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'Postcode' })).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{ name: 'Postcode' }` query matches the **label** attribute, and not the **name** attribute. Here's what the doc says:

> You can query the returned element(s) by their accessible name. The accessible name is for simple cases equal to e.g. the label of a form element, or the text content of a button, or the value of the aria-label attribute.

You can see details here: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole

Comment: Oh so for the name="postcode" what would I use then?

Comment: The basic idea of Testing Library is to test from the "user point of view", and that means that query must use "user accessible" attributes. `label` is user accessible, but `name` is not. Here's what they say (https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about): 
"With the name option you can filter the returned elements by their accessible name. This should be your top preference for just about everything."

Comment: ah so there's no need to test everything in Field? I'm migrating tests from enzyme and the original tests included :  expect(postcodeField.prop('name')).toEqual('postcode');
        expect(postcodeField.prop('label')).toBeTruthy();

Comment: I believe that Testing Library philosophy is different from Enzyme. "Test interface (user that is), not implementation (of component)"